# ASP.Net PostBack & Button Internal

Tags: asp.net

i worked for long time with windows apps using .net. for last 2 year i am working with asp.net. we often work with asp.net button control. when we click on button then postback occur and right server side event called by asp.net engine. i how link & image button causes postback when user click on those button.

when we work with link & image button then __doPostback js function is called and that causes form submit to server and request the same page and asp.net engine detect which control causes the postback from the hidden input control called eventTarget and invoke right event handler for that control.

but i dont know when we work with asp.net button control like

```
<asp:Button ID="SampleButton" runat="server" 
        Text="Submit" 
        OnClick="ButtonClick" />
```

when we click button then also form submit but how. i know that in this case `__doPostback` does not invoke because for button `__doPostback` is never rendered in the page. so in this case form submit but how asp.net engine detect which button causes postback and invoke right event handler?

how we get the data from textbox like txt1.text when postback occur. is it extracted from viewstate....am i right.

please answer for my 2 question. try to explain here instead of giving any url...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `asp:button` works differently by default. It outputs a standard HTML `Submit` button which posts back to the `Action` URL specified on the `form`. It therefore doesn't use events in the same way as other controls.

However if you add a `OnCommand` and assign `CommandName/CommandArgs` to the control, it will then cause the same event based callback behaviour as other controls. The same is true of `OnClick`. I assumed this used the same process as other controls but actually it's different.

It looks like it uses `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` to determine which form posted back, and the name of the submit button id is posted in the form as part of part of standard `HTML` form behaviuor. This is what is used to trigger the server-side events.

Comment: i was trying to know that when we click on button then how server side event like Button1_click is invoke...i know form submit...but i need to know the trick that how right event handler is invoke?

Comment: You explained how button events worked in the question. So I'm probably miss understanding.

Comment: if u know how event handler for asp.net button is invoke when use click on button then plzz explain...thanks

Comment: can u plzz explain how asp.net engine extract the button name from __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION hidden field which causes postback. please discuss in detail.thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple with respect to how controls postback. They do it in the same fashion as pure html solutions. There is a `Form` tag on the page. When the button is pressed it causes the form to submit a postback to the server.

Notice the action target of the form tag, it points to my aspx page
This is all generated by the aspx page itself.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
    <div>
         <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjA0OTM4MTAwNGRk5H5eaMNZp5tsD/GQ2iYj2p8J0as=" />
    </div>

    <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKmxpCiBgKSotaIC5iWtiHNi+oxYiuBULPgr5d0/WFu" />         
    </div>
    <div>
         <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="click me" id="btn1" />
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: i was trying to know that when we click on button then how server side event like Button1_click is invoke...i know form submit...but i need to know the trick that how right event handler is invoke?